# Buffer spatialline on one side

Tags: r, mapping, gis, spatial

I have a SpatialLinesDataFrame of many transects that I would like to buffer on only the North side of line using R.  Does anyone know of tool that mimics the 'Side Type' option for the Buffer tool in arcgis?  Thanks!

Comment: Please add more information, SO doesnt really like those open questions...

Comment: I don't mind answering them. I'd like to know if my answer is any good though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your transects are line segments that are monotonically increasing in X (and if not, I don't know how you can define what is north and what is south of a line) you can use this code. Basically it constructs the buffer with `gBuffer` and intersects that with a polygon created by extending the line segment south.

```
northbuff <- function(l1, width){
    if(length(l1)!=1){
        stop("line is not a single line element")
    }

    lines = l1@lines
    if(length(l1@lines)!=1){
        stop("line element is not a single line string")
    }

    bb = bbox(l1)
    xy = coordinates(l1@lines[[1]])[[1]]

    if(any(diff(xy[,1])<=0)){
        stop("x coord not monotone increasing")
    }

    xy = xy[order(xy[,1]),]
    nx = nrow(xy)

    xm = bb[1,1]-width*2

    ym = bb[2,1]-width*2

    xp = bb[1,2] + width*2

    coords = rbind(xy,
        c(xp,xy[nx,2]),
        c(xp,ym),
        c(xm,ym),
        c(xm,xy[1,2]),
        c(xy[1,1],xy[1,2])
        )
    p = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(coords)),ID=1)))

    b = gBuffer(l1, capStyle="FLAT", width=width)

    gDifference(b,p)

}
```

Test:

```
> require(sp)
> require(rgeos)
> l1 = readWKT("LINESTRING(0 0,1 5,4 5,5 2,8 2,9 4)")
> plot(northbuff(l1,.2))
> plot(l1,add=TRUE,col="blue",lwd=2)
```

You'll have to loop over your data frame to do this for each `SpatialLines` component.

If your transects are single line segments (ie a straight line from x,y to x',y') then its trivial and doable without `rgeos`. If your transects aren't strictly increasing in x-coordinate then you'll have to figure out how to define north and south of a line. This code could be easily modified to produce two polygons as output, which you could then input into a function to decide which was more 'North'.

Comment: Instead of north/south of line, how can you generate a right-side only buffer? This IS well-defined so long as the start/end coordinates are ordered.

Comment: If that's a problem you have, write it up as a question (assuming its not already been answered).